# Transform XML replacing nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to transform a XML. I tried XSLT transformations unsuccessfully. I am new on it.

Source:

```
<md>    
<mi>     
  <mt>rock</mt>
  <mt>classic</mt>
  <mt>pop</mt>
  <mv>
    <moid>blue</moid>
    <r>2</r>
    <r>4</r>
    <r>6</r>
  </mv>
  <mv>
    <moid>yellow</moid>
    <r>1</r>
    <r>5</r>
    <r>33</r>
  </mv>
  <mv>
    <moid>green</moid>
    <r>22</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>10</r>
  </mv>
</mi>
</md>
```

Target:

```
<md>    
<mi>     
  <mt>rock</mt>
  <mt>classic</mt>
  <mt>pop</mt>
  <mv>
    <moid>blue</moid>
    <rock>2</rock>
    <classic>4</classic>
    <pop>6</pop>
  </mv>
  <mv>
    <moid>yellow</moid>
    <rock>1</rock>
    <classic>5</classic>
    <pop>33</pop>
  </mv>
  <mv>
    <moid>green</moid>
    <rock>22</rock>
    <classic>0</classic>
    <pop>10</pop>
  </mv>     
</mi>
</md>
```

Basically, I need to replace 'r'tag nodes with the correct value of mt nodes based on the position.
For instance, the first 'r' tag node(the one with value 2) must be replaced with tag 'rock'.
Any advise on the solution would be appreciate.
Thanks and Best Regards,
Gav.

Comment: what have you tried? You have described in words what you need to do, you just need to figure out the match xpath expressions you need for your xslt. hint: //mv/r[1] will match ony the first r node under any mv node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="cat" match="mt" use="count(preceding-sibling::mt)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="r">
    <xsl:element name="{key('cat', count(preceding-sibling::r))}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element >
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your feedback. It is partially working. I only process the first mv node. Then it fails. It returns error: The empty string'' is not a valid name. ![error screenshot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AivZgV-jPDVj9nxXFpsi9fJ3X81-).